Plugin generated table unaffected by other plugins
I created a wordpress plugin to display discographies. The plugin inserts a table under the heading that shows the artist picture, etc. Including an intro and a text field where the content goes. If I put the content into a regular paragraph block, an autolinking plugin works perfectly and creates internal links based on tags. But the content from plugin is not affected at all. I tried adding classes to my table and divs according to the wordpress structure for the block area but that didn't do anything.
Now, the developer of the autolinking plugin states that, "TaxoPress will process content that is displayed using the_content(), which is the WordPress standard... Developers can use that, or they could run their output via: $content = apply_filters( ‘the_content’, $post->post_content );". Which leads to my question.
How do I set the attributes of a plugin injected table to mirror those of the block area?
This is the code adding content to the website through the plugin
   <!----------Intro-->

            <?php if ($row->ctp_intro): ?>
                <table id="contenido">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #ddd;">
                            <?php echo wpautop($row->ctp_intro); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php endif; ?>

<!--Read More-->    
            <?php if ($row->ctp_texto): ?>
                <table id="leermas">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cent" style="background: #fff;">
                            <span>
                                <a href="#" id="continuar-toggle" style="color: #657f9b;" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); toggleTexto();">Leer más</a>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
            
    <!----------Text-->

            <?php if ($row->ctp_texto): ?>
                <table id="oculto" style="border:0;">
                    <tr id="ctp-texto" style="display: none;">
                        <td style="background: #f8f8f8; border: 1px solid #ddd;">
                            <?php echo wpautop($row->ctp_texto); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

    <!----------Javascript Read More--> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function toggleTexto() {
                        var textoRow = document.getElementById("ctp-texto");
                        var continuarToggle = document.getElementById("continuar-toggle");
                        if (textoRow.style.display === "none") {
                            textoRow.style.display = "table-row";
                            continuarToggle.textContent = "Cerrar";
                        } else {
                            textoRow.style.display = "none";
                            continuarToggle.textContent = "Leer más";
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            <?php endif; ?>`

Among other things I tried using the classes and id's from the wordpress block area but I can't find a way to make this work. In a nutshell, there's some identification or tagging of the block area my plugin can't provide. Anyone seen something like this before?

"This is the code adding content to the website" - adding it where, and how?

Sorry, this plugin shows music album data. The plugin puts tables underneath a post tile. The last displays the content. Now, if I put content in regular wp blocks, the autolinking works, but it doesn't on the content of my plugin. I am an absolute newbie who just moved to wp from Joomla, so I'm just learning. One thing I played with after the post is priority of add_filter.  I changed this line ('the_content', 'ctp_display_custom_table') to add_filter('the_content', 'ctp_display_custom_table', any number). Only number 1 changed things but only shows the first link possible in the text.

you have to apply the filter to the content that you generate then try something like <?php echo apply_filters("the_content", $row->ctp_texto);?>

By default, the function the_content() will render the contents of the post_content column in the wp_posts table. But you can hook into this function using the_content to customise the post content between the database fetch and the rendering. Add your table using this hook, then it will be rendered by the_content() and the other plugin will see it and be able to operate on it.

I appreciate all the answers, and I played with your proposals to see what worked, but this plugin is just not gonna work. The code is cryptic beyond my means and they lack a forum to address questions. So, I tackled it myself. I'm not posting the code because my brother ask AI to create some regular expressions code to deal with accents and case, and I can't do it. But you can check out the website here. Again, thanks for all the comments. Really pushed me in the right direction, even if to just drop the other plugin.  https://www.lobotoradio.com/artistas/bandas/sentimiento-muerto/
